# C++ stringstream

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

How does stringstream work when you do this:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "123" << "abc";
```

Does it create a throwaway "123abc" string or does it do both operations consecutively to the stringstream?

I would like to replicate that functionality but no overload I do seems to work with two parameters like the above code...

Comment: I'm no expert, but << is an overloaded operator of the stringstream class  so I suppose that each operation one at a time by appending from the content from left to right.

Comment: Are you trying to create an operator<< for your class?

Comment: Yes but the default << overload only seems to work with one parameter like: ss << "123"; and not two parameters like the above...

Answer (score 13):

It's the equivalent of doing two seperate function calls of the << operator:

```
(ss.operator<<("123")).operator<<("abc")
```

so yes, it does both operations "consecutively".

Comment: -1 Wrong answer. There is no member function which takes `const char*`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it is equivalent to this:

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(ss, "123"), "abc");
```

Note that there is **no member** function which takes `const char*` as argument.  It is a non-member function, and `ss` is passed to it as first argument and `const char*` is passed as second argument. The function returns `std::ostream&` which then passed to it again. It is more like this:

```
print( print (ss, "123"), "abc"); //just for clarity
```

which means there are two function calls. Replace `print` with `std::operator<<`. Everything will be clear now.

Hope that helps.

---

The other answer which says this:

```
(ss.operator<<("123")).operator<<("abc") //copied from other answer (wrong)
```

is wrong! It is wrong because it assumes that `operator<<` which takes `const char*` as argument is a member function which is not true!

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream::operator<<(const char*)` returns a `std::stringstream&`.

This technique lets you "chain" it.

This is  not quite true -- but it is pretty much equivalent to the truth for your purposes.

A slightly more accurate statement is that `std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream&, const char*)` can be chained.

An even more accurate statement is that `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` exists, and `std::stringstream` is an `ostream`, then overload resolution on `<<` calls it.

Comment: -1 Wrong answer. There is no member function which takes `const char*`

Comment: Hmm it doesn't appear to let you chain <<=... bummer.  Like: ss <<= "123" << "abc";